# Observing a value in a loop and triggering an asynchronous function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, three.js, rxjs

I need to make a function that is asynchronous run when the value changes. It is inside a loop with a determined number of values and the other functions are being executed, but this one, because it has a fontloader, is not working. If the text comes from a file, it shows correctly, but I need to identify the value change (I'm using redux and it's inside useEffect. Everything that isn't from the fontloader is working fine), and show the text synchronously. I need this because the input can be via database or via user input. Via fileupload is loading, but does not update with an update (the textloader). Can someone help me?

function AppTextLoader:

```
const AppTextLoader = (scene: THREE.Scene,  prev_text: string | number, fontsize: number, parent: any, numPhases : number) => {

    const loader = new FontLoader();
    loader.load("gentilis_regular.typeface.json", function (font : any) {   

        const color = '#000000';
        const matDark = new LineBasicMaterial( {  color: color,  side: THREE.DoubleSide  } );

        if(typeof(prev_text)== 'number'){
            prev_text = prev_text.toString();
        }        
        const shapes = font.generateShapes( prev_text, fontsize);
        const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( shapes );
       
        const text = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, matDark );

        var p = numPhases * 0.33;
       
        var finalposition = new THREE.Vector3(1.3, p, 0);
        finalposition.add(parent.position);
        text.position.copy(finalposition);

        geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        scene.add( text );

    },
    
    );    
};
```

And here it shows the list. The size varies and each time the number increases, the new list has to be shown. The rest of the drawing (lots of lines) is rendering correctly... except the fontloader

```
   var tam = 10; //This value comes from the reducer
   for (i = 0; i < tam; i++){
      ... //More objects

      AppTextLoader(scene, text_label_od, od_label_size, myobject, numPhases);

      ... /More objects too
   }
```

I'm using rjsx which I'm using for something else. Can I use it to solve my problem?